# How to get the student academic progress?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

course Table

```
course_code   course_name      credit_points_reqd
1             Comp Science     300
2             Soft Engineering 300
```

subject Table

```
subject_code   subject_name    credit_points
CS123          C Prog          15
CS124          COBOL           15
```

enrolment table

```
student_id    student_name  course_code      subject_code      Results  
1             Lara Croft    1                CS123               70
1             Lara Croft    1                CS124               50
2             Tom Raider    2                CS123               60
2             Tom Raider    2                CS124               40
3             James Bond    1                CS123               NULL
3             James Bond    1                CS124               40
```

OUTPUT TABLE

```
student_name   course_name      credit_points_obt    credit_points_reqd
Lara Croft     Comp Science     30                   300          
Tom Raider     Soft Engineering 15                   300
```

I'm currently using TSQL. So here's the situation. I've prepared these tables to get the output like the way it i showed u up there. I need to calculate the credit points obtained. Credit points are achieved if the student receives > 50 for a subject they took. I want to ignore students that has not received any credit points at all (eg, James Bond is ignored as he has not achieved any points yet)

```
select student_name, course_name,credit_points_obt,credit_points_reqd
FROM enrolment (SELECT student_full_name, SUM(credit_points) AS credit_points_obt
               FROM enrolment
               GROUP BY student_id),
```

Totally stuck...I have no idea where to go now.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum conditionally to get points for subject. If none are given result will be null, so you filter out those student/course pairs in having clause.

I've changed > 50 condition to >= 50 because your results contradict your requirements. Also, by the data I'd say that you have omitted student table for brewity, but if you haven't, it is a must.

[Live test is @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ecd8/9).

```
select enrolment.student_name, 
       course.course_name,
       course.credit_points_reqd,
       sum(case when enrolment.results >= 50 
                then subject.credit_points 
            end) credit_points_obt
  FROM enrolment
 inner join course
    on enrolment.course_code = course.course_code
 inner join subject
    on enrolment.subject_code = subject.subject_code
 group by enrolment.student_name, 
          course.course_name, 
          course.credit_points_reqd
having sum(case when enrolment.results >= 50 
                then subject.credit_points 
            end) is not null
```

Comment: tx for introducing to SQL Fiddle

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović  , requirment says credit point are awarded if marks obtaind is grater than 50, so no need for enrolment.results >= 50

Comment: @zia If I have to quote myself: `I've changed > 50 condition to >= 50 because your results contradict your requirements`.

Comment: @Zia: More specifically, when talking about the *results*, Nikola is referring to Lara Croft's `30` in the OP's output. For, if the condition is really `> 50`, her result should be `15`.

Comment: @AndriyM Thank you. I've tried to get in-depth with this, but my english has failed me :-)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: The irony is, I understand you perfectly. :)

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović   and Andriy M , i think only nfnmy can tell where is the mistake (in requirement or in desired output) .